# Vitest - How to exclude specific files and folders?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vite, vitest

I am migrating my project from jest to vitest and I wanna exclude certain files and folders for both test and coverage, I am following the [docs](https://vitest.dev/config/#exclude) but "exclude" does not seem working, whenever I run some test, vitest throws an error that is coming from config folder and I don't have any test files there, inside the config folder I have bunch of config files including setupTests.ts and i18n specific config, the error is coming from the i18n.ts file. I am using vite 3 and Below is my vite config file, How else can I exclude files and folders?

Environment:

- Windows 11
- Node 16.14.0
- Vite 3.1.0
- Vitest 0.23.4
- List item

Edit: So it turns out the issue is in the setupTests.ts file where I am mocking the react-i18next, typescript was throwing an error when I tried to do "const actual = await vi.importActual(''react-i18next''); return {...actual, ...}" ignoring typescript works.

```
vi.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  ...vi.importActual('react-i18next'), // this didn't work
  useTranslation: () => [(key: any) => key],
}));


vi.mock('react-i18next', () => {
  const acutal = vi.importActual('react-i18next'), // this didn't work either
  return {
         ...actual, 
         useTranslation: () => [(key: any) => key],
   };
}); 



  vi.mock('react-i18next', async () => {
  const actual = await vi.importActual('react-i18next'); // this works
  return {
    // @ts-ignore  // have to put this here as typescript was complaining
    ...actual,
    useTranslation: () => [(key: any) => key],
  };
});
```

---

````
vite.config.ts

/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    tsconfigPaths(),
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './src/config/setupTests.ts',
    css: true,
    mockReset: true,
    restoreMocks: true,
    clearMocks: true,
    include: ['./src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],
    exclude: [
      '**/node_modules/**',
      '**/dist/**',
      '**/cypress/**',
      '**/.{idea,git,cache,output,temp}/**',
      './src/config/**',
    ],
    coverage: {
      exclude: ['./src/config'],
    },
  },
}); ```
````

Comment: If you've solved this yourself can you add it as an answer and mark it accepted?

Comment: About the syntax of vi.importActual, another solution I found somewhere is:

vi.mock('react-i18next', async () => {
  const actual = await vi.importActual<typeof import('react-i18next')>('react-i18next');
  return {
         ...actual, 
         useTranslation: () => [(key: any) => key],
   }
});

I found that when trying to migrate Jest unit tests to Vitest. Maybe it'll also help other people who found this post.

Answer (score 18):

We can use `exclude` attribute with in `test` configuration.

**vitest** configuartion can be modified in `vitest.config.ts` file. If we want to exclude shared folder packages, we could add `shared/*` to the `exclude` section as shown below

```
import { configDefaults } from 'vitest/config'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), tsconfigPaths()],
  test: {
    exclude:[
      ...configDefaults.exclude, 
      'shared/*'
    ]
  },
});
```

Here `configDefaults` contains the excluded default folders like `node_modules` which is available to use from `vitest/config` package. If we omit the `configDefaults.exclude` it will run checks in `node_modules` folder too.

More details can be found [here](https://vitest.dev/config/#watchignore) on official documentation.

Note: I have tested it as of 14th dec, 22

Comment: Tx! Note that the defaults are specified with broad patterns, like: `'**/cypress/**'`

Answer (score 7):

I managed to remove test folder from tests this way.

```
import { configDefaults, defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import path from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
      '@test': path.resolve(__dirname, './test'),
    },
  },
  test: {
    exclude: [...configDefaults.exclude, '**/test/**']
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tested approach.
You want to add excludes of your own but to keep defaults excluded too:
thus you unpack and add the array `...configDefaults.exclude,`

```
/**
 * https://vitest.dev/config/
 */

import {configDefaults, defineConfig, mergeConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import viteConfig from './vite.config'

export default mergeConfig(viteConfig, defineConfig({
  test: {
    exclude: [
      ...configDefaults.exclude, 
      '**/node_modules/**',
      '**/dist/**',
      '**/cypress/**',
      '**/.{idea,git,cache,output,temp}/**',
      './src/config/**',
    ],
  },
}))
```